# Asynctask progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a problem moving some of my initial code into an Asynctask.

I've been reading through several Asynctask examples as well as the Android developer article on Asynctask but I'm finding it hard to relate it to my code in a away I can understand.

The code below gives me an error and force closes when executing doInBackground(), and is Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

```
public class LoadingDialog extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>
{

    ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "", "Loading...");

    }

    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finalList.clear();
        eventList = database.getEvents();
        venueList = database.getVenues();
        finalList = createFinalList(eventList, venueList);

        return finalList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Home.this, finalList , R.layout.home,
                  new String[] { "eventName", "venueName", "startTime"},
                  new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_datetime });
                  setListAdapter(adapter);

                  lv = getListView();
                  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

                  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                  {
                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                      {
                          Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, EventInfo.class);

                          HashMap<String, String> map = finalList.get(position);
                          String eID = map.get("eventId");
                          String name = map.get("eventName");
                          String venue = map.get("venueName");
                          String lati = map.get("venueLatitude");
                          String longi = map.get("venueLongitude");
                          String opening = map.get("openingTimes");
                          String descrip = map.get("venueDescription");
                          String vID = map.get("venueId");
                          String email = map.get("venueEmail");
                          String phone = map.get("venuePhone");
                          String facebook = map.get("venueFacebook");
                          String twitter = map.get("venueTwitter");

                          i.putExtra("itemId", eID);
                          i.putExtra("itemName", name);
                          i.putExtra("venueName", venue);
                          i.putExtra("venueLati", lati);
                          i.putExtra("venueLong", longi);
                          i.putExtra("opening", opening);
                          i.putExtra("venueDescription", descrip);
                          i.putExtra("venueID", vID);
                          i.putExtra("venueEmail", email);
                          i.putExtra("venuePhone", phone);
                          i.putExtra("venueFacebook", facebook);
                          i.putExtra("venueTwitter", twitter);
                          startActivityForResult(i, 0);               

                      }
                  });

    }


}
```

This is part of the home class:

```
public class Home extends ListActivity {
int eventid;
String[] venue = null;
String[] name = null;
private SqlParser database = new SqlParser();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> eventList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> venueList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> finalList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
ListView lv = null;
```

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: what does `createFinalList` do? according to your description, the errors comes from there or from your database

Answer (score -1):

create this line   **ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);** in out side the AsynTask class

Comment: the creation of the ProgressDialog is in the onPreExecute, which is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: then this line is not reqiured ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);

Comment: first remove that line and excute then see the output

Comment: The ProgressDialog isn't created in the onPreExecute method, it's just setting the variable show. I moved "ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Home.this);" out of the asynctask sub class but it made no difference and gives me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Just check your code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Home.this, finalList , R.layout.home,
                  new String[] { "eventName", "venueName", "startTime"},
                  new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_datetime });
                  setListAdapter(adapter);

                  lv = getListView();
```

Here you are trying to set adapter to listview before getting ListView actually.

It should be like:

```
 lv = getListView();
 setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: there is no relation between those 2 lines.

Comment: @njzk2 Are you sure? Let me how can you be able to set adapter before you got ListView.

Comment: i am quite sure, yes. getListView returns a ListView. setListAdapter is a method of the ListActivity class. The particular lv variable is not known by the super.